# Add event handler to each using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications

How would I use .on and .each together?

```
$('[id^="thing"]').each(???)
```

A single one would be:

```
 $("#button").on("click", function() {
                    console.log(this.id)
 })
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `.on()` on a jQuery object containing multiple elements will add the handler to every element.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('[id^="thing"]').on("click", function() { });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this version to specify a selector, to specify which child elements should trigger the event.

```
$('[id^="thing"]').on('click','button (or whatever selector)', function(){
  // "this" refers to triggering element
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
   $('[id^="thing"]').each(function(i, el) {
        $(el).on("click", function() {                 
       })
    });
```

Comment: @RohitAgrawal - no it won't, it binds to each matched element once.

Answer (score -1):

you **don't need `.each` with `.on`**,

the thing you want can be done only with this -

**A GOOD WAY**

```
$(document).on('click','[id^="thing"]', function() {
    console.log(this.id)
});
```

it can be done as you want it but as it will impact performance with no reason

**THE WAY YOU WANT BUT TO BE AVOIDED**

```
$('[id^="thing"]').each(function(){
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    console.log(this.id)
  });
});
```

and if you will use `.on` inside `.each` you may
end up in **binding the event multiple times** in this way

**The WRONG WAY**

```
$('[id^="thing"]').each(function(){
  $('[id^="thing"]').on('click', function() {
    console.log(this.id)
  });
});
```